# R list from variables using variable names

Tags: r

I've looked extensively for a solution for this very simple task and though I have a solution, it seems like there must be a better way. The task is to create a list from a set of variables, using the variable names as names for each element in the list, e.g.:

```
a <- 2
b <- 'foo'
c <- 1:4
```

My current solution:

```
named.list <- function(...) { 
    l <- list(...)
    names(l) <- sapply(substitute(list(...)), deparse)[-1]
    l 
}
named.list(a,b,c)
```

Produces:

```
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] "foo"

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: +1 For reproducible example. I don't think this is a particularly *bad* way of doing it myself. But you can avoid the `sapply` call.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A couple of ways I can think of include `mget` (make assumptions about the environment your objects are located in):

```
mget( c("a","b","c") )
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] "foo"

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Or as an edit to your function, you could use, `match.call` like this:

```
named.list <- function(...) { 
    l <- list(...)
    names(l) <- as.character( match.call()[-1] )
   l
}
named.list( a,b,c)
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] "foo"

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Or you can do it in one go using `setNames` like this:

```
named.list <- function(...) { 
    l <- setNames( list(...) , as.character( match.call()[-1]) ) 
    l
}

named.list( a,b,c)
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] "foo"

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: +1! I would `as.list(match.call())[-1]`. and `expand.dots = TRUE` is set by default

Comment: @agstudy thanks and I took heed of your tip about `expand.dots`!

Comment: This won't allow you to name something in the call, e.g. ```r named.list(a, b, c = 1:4)``` will not name c.  You could set ```l <- list(...)``` then add the names from match.call to elements without names in order to keep names for variables named in the call.

Answer (score 10):

If you already using tidyverse packages, then you might be interested in using the  `tibble::lst` function which does this

```
tibble::lst(a, b, c)
# $a
#  [1] 2
#  
# $b
# [1] "foo"
# 
# $c
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Is there a function that does the opposite, creates variables from named list? I can also post a question if you want.

Comment: @mihagazvoda: `list2env` does what you want